# Magento 2 custom child theme add favicons

Tags: magento2, meta-tags, favicons

I'm trying to add various favicons to a custom theme.

I've added `/theme_dir/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and within I've tried the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- custom favicons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/apple-icon-57x57.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/apple-icon-60x60.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/apple-icon-72x72.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/apple-icon-76x76.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/apple-icon-114x114.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/apple-icon-120x120.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/apple-icon-144x144.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/apple-icon-152x152.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="iconsapple-icon-180x180.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="icons/android-icon-192x192.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png"/>

        <link rel="manifest" href="icons/manifest.json"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icons/ms-icon-144x144.png"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

But only the meta tags are placed in the frontend html, all `<link>` items are not rendered apart from the manifest, which doesn't actually give the correct link:

```
<link  rel="manifest" href="icons/manifest.json" href="http://localhost/pub/static/frontend/Name/theme_dir/de_DE" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is that `href` needs to be replaced with `src`. Also you need to place or copy the normal favicon.ico file inside the `theme_dir/web/` directory. All my other icons are in `theme_dir/web/icons/`

The following now works for me:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Custom Favicons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" src="icons/apple-icon-57x57.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" src="icons/apple-icon-60x60.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" src="icons/apple-icon-72x72.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" src="icons/apple-icon-76x76.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" src="icons/apple-icon-114x114.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" src="icons/apple-icon-120x120.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" src="icons/apple-icon-144x144.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" src="icons/apple-icon-152x152.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" src="icons/apple-icon-180x180.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" src="icons/android-icon-192x192.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" src="icons/favicon-32x32.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" src="icons/favicon-96x96.png"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" src="icons/favicon-16x16.png"/>
        <link rel="manifest" src="icons/manifest.json"/>

        <!-- Custom Metas -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icons/ms-icon-144x144.png"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To override the default 16px x 16px favicon manually, add your custom favicon.ico in the /Magento_Theme/web/directory.

To add favicon icons of other sizes, take the following steps:

Add your icons in the /Magento_Theme/web/ directory.    In the /Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml layout    file specify the paths to the icons and their sizes.

For example, if you added a favicon-32x32.png icon and want it to be used as a 32px x 32px favicon, your default_head_blocks.xml would be like following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
    </head>
</page>
```